# How do we create Unique Constraint in lift-mapper

Tags: scala, lift, mapper

How can we create a unique constraint in lift's mapper ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that by adding the following in your MetaMapper object

`override def dbIndexes=UniqueIndex(<name-of-the-field>)::super.dbIndexes`

comma separated list of fields can also be provided

for example - `UniqueIndex(name,dob)`

Comment: perhaps `super.dbIndexs` should instead be `super.dbIndexes`?